# Find all the digits in a string

Tags: homework, assembly, x86

`S` is a given character string, then I have to find all the digits characters of `S`. Did I make it unnecessarily complicated?

```
bits 32

global start        

extern exit
import exit msvcrt.dll

segment data use32 class=data
    s db '+', 'r', '0', '8', '8', '1', 'i', '5'
    len equ $ - s
    digits db '012345789'
    d times len db 0
segment code use32 class=code
    start:
        mov ecx, len
        
        mov esi,0
        mov ebx,0
        
        jecxz end_prog
        
        repeat_this:
            push ecx
            mov al, [s + esi]
            mov ecx, 10
            mov edi, digits
            find:
                scasb
                jz found
            loop find
            
            jmp next
            
            found:
                mov edi, ebx
                inc ebx
                mov [d + edi], al
            
            next:   
                inc esi
                pop ecx
        loop repeat_this
        
        end_prog:
        
        push    dword 0
        call    [exit]
```

Comment: Don't forget that your title should only state the **task accomplished by the code** and nothing else. I also recommend you to add more information about your code in the body to help reviewers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Did I make it unnecessarily complicated?

- You can replace

  ```
  find:
    scasb
    jz    found
    loop  find
    jmp   next
  ```

  by the simpler

  ```
    repne scasb
    jne   next
  ```

  The use of the `SCASB` instruction here depends on the direction flag DF being in the clear state (`CLD`). It is a safe assumption that this will be the case. Nonethesless prudent programmers will at least at program start include one `CLD` instruction.
  If ever you find that you need to reverse the direction for the string primitives by the use of `STD`, you should always issue a restoring `CLD` as soon as possible (once the string operation has finished). Why is this? Well, just as you can expect the direction flag to be clear, any library functions that your program invokes expect the same thing. During normal program execution `DF=0` is almost true 100% of the time. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490225/the-probability-of-selected-eflags-bits).
- No need to use the extra register `EDI` in:

  ```
  mov   edi, ebx
  inc   ebx
  mov   [d + edi], al
  ```

  Just write:

  ```
  mov   [d + ebx], al
  inc   ebx
  ```
- The digits have well-known ASCII codes. Finding a digit is just a matter of comparing `AL` with the range 48 to 57. I find scanning that *digits* string a bit overkill, although at times that could be a good way. When the character codes aren't contiguous.

  ```
    mov   ecx, len
    jecxz end_prog
    xor   esi, esi
    xor   ebx, ebx
  repeat_this:
    mov   al, [s + esi]
    cmp   al, '0'
    jb    next
    cmp   al, '9'
    ja    next
    mov   [d + ebx], al
    inc   ebx
  next:   
    inc   esi
    loop  repeat_this
  ```

  Clearing a register is best done using `XOR <reg>,<reg>`.

---

This shorter version uses the string primitives and avoids using the slow `LOOP` instruction:

```
    mov   ecx, len
    mov   esi, s
    mov   edi, d
    jmp   next
  repeat_this:
    lodsb
    cmp   al, '0'
    jb    next
    cmp   al, '9'
    ja    next
    stosb
  next:
    sub   ecx, 1  
    jnb   repeat_this
```

Comment: Good review! It might be worth commenting on the Direction Flag and what are and are not safe assumptions about its state.

Comment: You can also range-check more efficiently with `lea edx, [eax-'0']` / `cmp dl, 9` / `ja next`.  Of course if you care about performance on modern CPUs you'd use `movzx eax, [esi]` / `inc esi` to load, instead of letting lodsb merge into the old EAX value.  ([Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502)). 
 `lodsb` and `stosb` aren't fast in general.